# Changing Tint Color on notification received

Tags: swift

I wrote a function to change the navbar color:

```
func changeNavigationBarTitleAndAppearance(title title:String) {

    switch (title) {

    case "active":
        self.title = "Einsatzbereit".uppercaseString

        if let navController = navigationController {
            navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 73.0/255.0, green: 181.0/255.0, blue: 177.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }

    case "inactive":
        self.title = "Inaktiv".uppercaseString

        if let navController = navigationController {
            navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 40.0/255.0, green: 51.0/255.0, blue: 57.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }

    case "dispatch":
        self.title = "Alarmierung".uppercaseString

        if let navController = navigationController {
            navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 208.0/255.0, green: 2.0/255.0, blue: 27.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }

    default:
        return
    }


func dispatchReceived(notification: NSNotification) {
    print(notification.name)
    switch (notification.name) {

    case "DISPATCH_RECEIVED":
        self.changeNavigationBarTitleAndAppearance(title: "dispatch")

    case "DISPATCH_ACCEPTED":
        self.changeNavigationBarTitleAndAppearance(title: "active")

    case "DISPATCH_DECLINED":
        self.changeNavigationBarTitleAndAppearance(title: "active")

    default:
        return
    }

}
```

The first notification I send is: "DISPATCH_RECEIVED". As expected the navbar tint turns red as described in the function. But when I send the message "DISPATCH_DECLINED", the function gets called as expected to change the color, but nothing happens anymore and everything stays red.

The view controller observes:

```
self.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "dispatchReceived:", name: "DISPATCH_RECEIVED", object: nil)

self.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "dispatchReceived:", name: "DISPATCH_DECLINED", object: nil)
```

and calls the associated method like expected.

The whole process works well for the first call when I send the notification for "DISPATCH`changeNavigationBarTitleAndAppearance(title: "dispatch")`

But when I send the second notification

Comment: Is your function running on main thread? Is the navigation controller not nil?

Comment: awesome! it was the thread.. the actionsheet is used within a backgroundthread.... i set the notificiation post within this thread to the mainthread and it works perfectly well!!! thanks